# zcat fails to make a boot image for Ubuntu USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, disk-image

`mount` says this about the drive in question:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/3433-3231 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1001,gid=1002,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush)
```

This is the response I get when trying `zcat` on the boot image to the unmounted drive at `/dev/sdb1`

```
root@gemeni:/home/a1# zcat -v boot.img.gz > /dev/sdb1
boot.img.gz:    
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

This is what happens when I try it without the part number:

```
root@gemeni:/home/a1# zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdb
bash: /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

I'm working from [this tutorial](http://blog.aragirn.net/odds-and-ends/install-ubuntu-from-a-flash-disk/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one is the crucial error message:

```
bash: /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

So it seems that `/dev/sdb` is no longer connected to the system when you try using it; if you unmounted it using Nautilus' menu, it's likely that the whole USB device has been de-activated. (Look in the last lines of `/var/log/syslog` for confirmation.)

Try:

1. Plug the USB stick in
2. Look up what ID the auto-mounter assigns to it: run `mount | fgrep /dev/sdb`, this will show a line like `/dev/sdb on /media/3433-3231 ...` (the actual numbers may change)
3. unmount it *from the command line:*

   ```
   sudo umount /media/3433-3231
   ```
4. Now you should be able to proceed with your tutorial (as root):

   ```
   zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `/dev/sdb1` is large enough for the uncompressed disk image?  (The error message complains there is not enough space...)

Also, `/dev/sdb1` is not a drive but a partition (the tutorial you follow uses a drive).  Using a partition is certainly possible, but will require extra work (configuring a bootloader in the MBR).

Also, you might want to use a GUI tool like USB Creator (installed by default on Ubuntu under **System > Administration**) or [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) ([Ubuntu package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unetbootin)) instead of doing this manually.

Comment: Big enough: Yes. It's an 8 gb USB drive... Is there a way to mount it as a drive? GUI: I'd rather not use the GUI tool in this case.

Comment: Using the drive instead of a partition => use /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sdb1

Comment: yeah, also yields an error. amended question to reflect